# Delete cached instances of object

Tags: c#

I have factory class like below:

```
class SomeFactory
{
    private Dictionary<string, Boo> cache;
    private Timer cleanup;

    SomeFactory()
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<string, Boo>();
        cleanup = new Timer(60 * 1000);
        cleanup += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { cache.Clear(); }
        cleanup.Start();
    }

    public Boo GetBoo(string serial, int year)
    {
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(serial))
        {
            Boo boo = new Boo(serial, year);
            boo.inject(...); // some stuff
            cache.Add(serial, boo);
        }
        return cache[serial];
    }

    ...

}
```

Is you can see I caches created `Boo` instances. Usually `Boo` is necessary for a moment, when user want just take a quick look, then can be free. Only one instance of `Book` is actually edited, and should be stored for long time. After long time of using application there may be a lot unused `Boo` objects. There is a design pattern to deal with this kind of situation? How bad my cleanup code is?

Comment: Is it good? Maybe. Depends on what the application is and context(s) accessing the data. Some applications like ASP.NET have built in caching providers you can take advantage of. With others a sinleton factory is all you need. It really just depends.

Comment: There are also plenty of existing questions out there with answers and tools about how to cache and cleanup data. Start there.

Comment: Your code is not (thread) safe, so sooner or later it will crash or produce unexpected results.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `ContainsKey` like that. _Use `TryGetValue` to avoid looking up the key twice._ For your actual issue, consider using `MemoryCache` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.default(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: The better solution to my problem will be involve DI container, which ones of function is take care about object lifetime. Good link about it:https://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/

Comment: From that link, what Autofac feature are you using to provide caching?

Comment: @mjwills I redesigned my app, that `Boo` instances are provided by autofac, I control lifetime by http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Environment (particular WebApplications and Services), there are special ways to go about caching. The Lifecycle of the Instances, scopes of variables and Thread level seperation simply make this nessesary.

Asuming a simple local application, the usual way to go about Caching is to use a [Weak references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references). Strong references prevent the GC from Collecting this instance. Weak References do not. But you can try to get a StrongReference from them.  At this point one of two things will happen:

1. You get a strong reference.
2. The instance was already collected. You have to re-creat it from scratch.

Comment: Weak references is exactly what I need.